# Python, weird value when trying to calculate error of linear regression

Tags: python, excel

I am newbie to python and i'm assigned to create my own algorithm to solve linear regression without using any import. The problem is, when i try my program to calculate the error, it give the strange value (i compare it with calculation from microsoft excel). Here's my program:

```
x=[1.,1.,2.,2.,2.,2.,2.,2.,2.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,3.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,4.,5.,5.,5.,5.,5.,5.,5.,5.,6.]
y=[67.,62.,109.,83.,91.,88.,123.,100.,109.,137.,131.,122.,122.,118.,115.,131.,143.,142.,122.,140.,150.,140.,150,150.,140.,150.,130.,130.,138.,135.,146.,146.,145.,145.,144.,140.,150.,152.,157.,155.,153.,154.,158.,162.,161.,162.,165.,171.,162.,169.,167.,150.,170.,140.,140.,150.,150.,150.,160.,150.,150.,150.,150.,140.,160.,170.,160.,160.,170.,171.,188.,170.,150.,150.,160.,160.,180.,170.]
sumx = 0
sumxdoubled = 0
sumxsquare = 0
sumxy = 0
meanx = 0
sumy = 0
sumerror = 0
n= 78

for i in range(78):
   sumxy = sumxy + (x[i] * y[i])
print("Total (x.y) : ",sumxy)

for i in range(78):
   sumx = sumx + x[i]
print("Total x : ",sumx)

for i in range(78):
   sumxsquare = sumxsquare + (x[i] ** 2)
print("Total (x^2) : ",sumxsquare)

sumxdoubled = sumx ** 2
print("(Total x)^2 : ",sumxdoubled)

meanx = sumx / n
print("Average x : ",meanx)

for i in range(78):
   sumy = sumy + y[i]
print("Total y : ",sumy)

meany = sumy / n
print("Average y : ",meany)

a1 = ((n*sumxy) - (sumx * sumy)) / ((n*sumxsquare) - sumxdoubled)
print("a1 = ",a1)

a0 = meany - a1 * meanx
print("a0 = ",a0)
for i in range (78):
   sumerror = sumerror + (y[i] - a0 - (a1 * x[i]))
print("Total error = ",sumerror)
```

And the output is:

```
Total (x.y) :  42117.0
Total x :  283.0
Total (x^2) :  1093.0
(Total x)^2 :  80089.0
Average x :  3.628205128205128
Total y :  11201.0
Average y :  143.60256410256412
a1 =  22.312294288480153
a0 =  62.64898354307843
Total error =  -7.673861546209082e-13
```

The error value when i try the same data with microsoft excel is `-14.25`

Why does the python gives the value that is not even close to excel value `-14.25`? I couldn't guess what's wrong with the program, because i'm sure i'm using the right algorithm to calculate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with python, so much as with your math.
When you calculate your error, first you have to add brackets to make sure you're doing the correct calculation:

```
sumerror = sumerror + (y[i] - a0 - (a1 * x[i])) # <-- missing brackets
sumerror = sumerror + (y[i] - (a0 - (a1 * x[i])))
```

But then you aren't even finished, you need to divide this result by n then take the square root.

```
>>> sumerror = (sumerror / n)**0.5
>>> print("Total error = ",sumerror)
Total error = 12.724274483009689
```

Since this is a question in a programming forum, I'll point out that while you're there you can use a lof of inbuilt functions to make things easier on yourself.

```
for i in range(78):
   sumxy = sumxy + (x[i] * y[i])
```

Is bad, you've hard coded the length of your lists which you would need to update every time you use new lists.  There is an inbuilt function len() which will get this for you.  In this case that isn't even necessary though, you can just use sum() and the slightly more advanced zip to join the lists together.

```
# zip(x, y) returns an iterator like [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), ..., (xn, yn)]
>>> sumxy = sum(x*y for x, y in zip(x, y))
>>> print("Total (x.y) : ",sumxy)
Total (x.y) :  42117.0
```